# How to group elements using an Angular filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

[image]

I am facing problem in grouping the elements of same id

```
<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in players | groupBy: 'team'">
  Group name: {{ key }}
 <li ng-repeat="player in value">
  player: {{ player.name }} 
 </li>
```

js code:

```
$scope.players = [
{name: 'Gene', team: 'alpha'},
{name: 'George', team: 'beta'},
{name: 'Steve', team: 'gamma'},
{name: 'Paula', team: 'beta'},
{name: 'Scruath', team: 'gamma'}
];
```

I get [this type](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/unpr?p0=groupByFilterProvider%20%3C-%20groupByFilter) of error :

> Error: $injector:unpr
>   Unknown Provider
>   Unknown provider: `groupByFilterProvider <- groupByFilter`

Comment: It is not mandatory, but it is encouraged to accept or upvote helpful answers. There's two answers below that would benefit from your attention.

Answer (score 1):

`groupBy` isn't built in filter provided by Angular, you could use [angular.filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter%60) module which can provide you many filters like groupBy, flatten, filterBy, pluck, etc.

```
//added angular.filter module after adding its reference
angular.module('myApp', ['angular.filter']);
```

[**Here**](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#table-of-contents) you can find list of built in filter

Answer (score 0):

Write a specific function to group your data:

```js
function Main($scope) {
  $scope.players = [
    {name: 'Gene', team: 'alpha'},
    {name: 'George', team: 'beta'},
    {name: 'Steve', team: 'gamma'},
    {name: 'Paula', team: 'beta'},
    {name: 'Scruath', team: 'gamma'}
  ];

  var indexedTeams = [];

  $scope.playersToFilter = function() {
    indexedTeams = [];
    return $scope.players;
  }

  $scope.filterTeams = function(player) {
    var teamIsNew = indexedTeams.indexOf(player.team) == -1;
    if (teamIsNew) {
      indexedTeams.push(player.team);
    }
    return teamIsNew;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="Main">
  <div ng-repeat="p in playersToFilter() | filter:filterTeams">
    <b>{{p.team}}</b>
    <li ng-repeat="player in players | filter:{team: p.team}">{{player.name}}</li>
  </div>
</div>
```